# How to write a code in Kotlin, that prints three text lines in a column (first second third)

Tags: kotlin

I've tried these two options and the IDE returns both options to be correct. However, when I copy/paste the same codes in Hyperskill Studying platform, it says "incorrect".
I can't understand where I am going wrong. Appreciate your help.

The three lines are:
first
second
third

These must return as columns

Solution 1

```
fun main() {
    print("first   ")
    print("second   ")
    print("third")
}
```

Solution_2

```
fun main() {
    val column1 = "first"
    val column2 = "second"
    val column3 = "third"
    val header = column1 + " " + column2 + " " + column3
    println(header)
}
```

Comment: Columns of how many characters? What is the expected result?

Comment: The three lines are: first second third

Comment: Just printing the values of the lines separated by a single whitespace does not really make it column-wise. What is the exact task?

Comment: The three words "first, second, third" are all in separate lines.  I need to write a code to print in a column. I.e. in one line.  I tried the print() method as well as val() method. Both options are returning "ok" in the IDE.  However, in my practice lab, it is saying incorrect. 
  Link is here:  https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/4432#comment

Comment: If you want them on separate *lines* (i.e. forming a single column) you can use `println`, which prints your text as a line and adds a line break, so the next thing you print starts on the next line. You can also add the line breaks yourself with the `\n` character (like in *Cccccwq*'s answer) if it's more convenient (but you still might want to use `println` so it adds one at the end, and the next print starts on a separate line)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("first\nsecond\nthird")
```

Comment: \n is for next line right?  Therefore, the three strings/words will be printed in separate lines.

Comment: According to the question, this answer would be incorrect, because they are printed in separate lines.  However, the solution has come out correct in my project.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.format` here:

##### values in a row

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val column1 = "first"
    val column2 = "second"
    val column3 = "third"
    val rowPattern = "%7s%7s%7s"
    println(rowPattern.format(column1, column2, column3))
}
```

Output:

```
  first second  third
```

##### values in a column

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val column1 = "first"
    val column2 = "second"
    val column3 = "third"
    val colPattern = "%7s\n%7s\n%7s"
    println(colPattern.format(column1, column2, column3))
}
```

Output

```
  first
 second
  third
```

Please note: The `7` in the pattern `String`s defines the amount of characters used for the argument. The example `String`s all have a length < 7, which leads to leading whitespaces to the left of each argument in the pattern. You can reverse this order if you write `-7`…
e.g. the (row) pattern `"%-7s%-7s%-7s"` will produce

```
first  second third
```

---

You can also just use the length of the arguments by not providing any number, so a pattern of `"%s\n%s\n%s"` will just put every argument in a new line without leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you for explaining both options in details and I've learnt a lot here.  However, the solution print("first\nsecond\nthird") by Cccccwq turned out to be correct. Thank you both very much.  I am kicking myself for not reading this very easy question correctly!